# Slightsearch hijacking google chrome reset not working

Tags: google-chrome, search-engine, malware

I recently got malware installed on my PC that contained software that infected my google chrome, by hijacking my default search engine. I tried:

1. Removing newly installed programs from PC, using windows utility.
2. Using Microsoft essentials and hitman pro to fully scan my computer (removed  3 malware of which one was a program and the other adware)
3. Removing the newly created extension in google chrome.

I tried to change my search engine back to default but I states that the administrator of the program has rights to change the search engine. I then:

1. Reset my chrome, and restarted my PC. Didn't work.
2. Then went to registry and deleted all traces of slightsearch and any keys relating to default search engine of chrome.

Restarted PC and nothing has changed at all. My home page is working as normal and I can search google when searching using the URL bar then it redirects to slightsearch.

Lastly, this malware even stared showing me ads on my desktop, when not in Chrome. Scanning and removing the malicious files solved this issue, but the search engine issue still exists.

Please help me solve this issue. And with all due respect, please do not give me the usual tips for removing popups or adware, because as already stated I have done all of these steps. Will appreciate any new solutions.

Regards

Comment: please go through these steps  https://malwaretips.com/blogs/remove-adware-popup-ads/
and check this also   https://malwaretips.com/blogs/remove-ads-not-by-this-site/

Comment: Hi Pardeep, as stated in my explination I have done all these steps, and more. I did not use malwarebytes or one of those other malware cleaners, but did use MS security essentials and hitmanPRO. Still not working @PardeepPathania

Comment: please do one thing uninstall Chrome and install it again after that go to control panel and delete unwanted software

Comment: I want to remove the hijacking software without uninstall. I already went to control panel and uninstalled unwanted software, so why would doing it again help me?

Comment: try this https://malwaretips.com/blogs/remove-browser-redirect-virus/

Comment: Ok so I also uninstalled Chrome and reinstalled it. The problem is still the same...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I eventually fixed the problem.

I had to delete files under c:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicyUsers

Checked all the files contained in GroupPolicyUsers and then deleted those that related to chrome and that was messing with my Registry.

Restarted chrome and now all is fixed!